# cannot boot kali usb

Tags: usb-flash-drive, dd, kali-linux

I downloaded - from http://www.kali.org/downloads/ - Kali Linux 32 bit ISO

and then sha1sum-ed.

blkid shows my usb on /dev/sdc1

then

```
dd if=<path-to-kali.iso> of=/dev/sdc
```

(I have also tried the same command + bs=512k

My usb is  4.2 GB.

My bios is set  up to boot on usb first ( I have already booted from usb several time (xubuntu, ubuntu))

When I launch my laptop, it does not boot on usb but hdd (I can see 'Kali live' usb mounted once I booted on my hdd (which is xubuntu).

I have read somewhere that the bios needs to be set up with 'secure boot option' disabled. I havent got that option on my bios.

I dont know what to do now.

any idea folks?

thank you very much.

Comment: shouldn't of= be /dev/sdc1 instead of /dev/sdc?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your manufacturer you could hold down F2, F12, Esc (escape), or F9. Those are the ones I know (again, depending on the manufacturer) will bring up a boot menu of bootable drives. You may have done something wrong, and the drive isn't bootable so the computer id skipping it, if that is the case.